# Would Firefox keep history if I clean it on another synced PC?

Tags: firefox, browser, sync

I have my Firefox synced to multiple devices(office computer, PC and android phone) and I would like to know what if I clean history on one computer in firefox. Would another firefox in another device would keep it's history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Firefox Sync, clearing history on one device apparently temporarily hides the history on that device. Here is why.

The history is actually deleted on the current device, and is **marked for deletion** on the servers, except that the history may already be on your other devices, where it is treated as new data and **not** marked for deletion. Subsequently, sooner or later, the history may also appear on the current device.

If you are using Firefox Sync, the most reliable way to **delete all** browsing history is to delete your sync account and create a new one. Alternatively, you could log into your account, explicitly disable syncing of browsing history, clear history on all your devices where you use Firefox Sync and then re-enable syncing. Unfortunately, this does not guarantee that all the history will be deleted because you never know how long it will take the data to be **actually** deleted from the servers, so some (or all) of the history may still continue to show up on your devices.

Comment: Very helpful, or should I just discountinue with firefox as this is a very serious problem. One cannot have access to all his devices all the time.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend discontinuing use of Firefox. In my opinion, Firefox is the best browser in terms of customizability (unless that is not an issue to you). By the way, the sync problem is not limited to Firefox. I have experienced the same with (Google) Chrome: you clear all history on one device, log into your sync account weeks later and the browsing history is all back. As long as your other devices have the browsing history locally, temporarily disabling sync does not help.